# Complete Deletion of an App on iPad

Tags: applications, macos

I have downloaded a game on my iPad (hopefully free), played for a while. Then, after several days, the app crashed. The current situation is that this app starts, but during initial loading, it crashes. I've deleted the app and then re-downloaded it from the App Store, believing that the corrupted file had been deleted too. But the problem stays the same: crash at startup.

So my question is: when I delete an app, does it leave some files on the system? And if it is the case, is it possible to get totally rid of an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way iOS sandboxes apps, when you delete an app, it along with its data are gone. The only remains are in the App Store purchase history. The iOS security means you can't easily undelete these files via a jailbreak - so if you want to ensure the [data gets securely erased](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4175), you should erase all contents and settings which will either destroy the key used to encrypt.

Don't forget to delete the app from iTunes on any computers you have and then make a backup of your iPad with the app deleted. That gets rid of two other potential copies of the app.

The game is probably just buggy. You can tell the developer and make sure to mention what iDevice you have, its iOS version, and specifically what the bug is.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might not be with the app or it's data, but something else on your iPad.  Try rebooting (slide to power off) your iPad, and then reinstalling the app.